# How to filter results of wikidata to specific language

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a query to get all Capitals. (Capital Cities)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Stadt ?label ?Staat ?StaatLabel ?geographische_Koordinaten ?StadtLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Stadt wdt:P31 wd:Q5119.
  ?Stadt rdfs:label ?label.
  OPTIONAL { ?Stadt wdt:P17 ?Staat. }
  OPTIONAL { ?Stadt wdt:P625 ?geographische_Koordinaten. }
}
LIMIT 100
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FStadt%20%3Flabel%20%3FStaat%20%3FStaatLabel%20%3Fgeographische_Koordinaten%20%3FStadtLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3FStadt%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5119.%0A%20%20%3FStadt%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3FStadt%20wdt%3AP17%20%3FStaat.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3FStadt%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fgeographische_Koordinaten.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100)

and the result is:

```
 wd:Q61     Washington D.C.     wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
wd:Q61  Washington D. C.    wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
wd:Q61  واشنگٹن ڈی سی   wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
wd:Q61  Washington D.C.     wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
wd:Q61  واشنګټن ډي سي   wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
wd:Q61  Вашингтон   wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
wd:Q61  ওয়াশিংটন, ডি.সি.   wd:Q30  Vereinigte Staaten  Point(-77.036666666 38.895)     Washington, D.C.
```

I get many results of the same city in several languages.

How can I filter the query so I get only one result per city with the english label ?

*** UPDATED ***

Thanks for helping Stanislav. You answered the question. My new query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Stadt ?label ?StadtLabel ?Staat ?StaatLabel ?geographische_Koordinaten WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  ?Stadt wdt:P31 wd:Q5119.
  ?Stadt wdt:P17 ?Staat.
  OPTIONAL { ?Stadt wdt:P625 ?geographische_Koordinaten. }
}
LIMIT 100
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FStadt%20%3Flabel%20%3FStadtLabel%20%3FStaat%20%3FStaatLabel%20%3Fgeographische_Koordinaten%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3FStadt%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5119.%0A%20%20%3FStadt%20wdt%3AP17%20%3FStaat.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3FStadt%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fgeographische_Koordinaten.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100)

May I ask a following question ? Why do I get not only the capitals with this query ? Why "?Stadt wdt:P31 wd:Q5119." is ignored ?

Comment: Just comment out the `?Stadt rdfs:label ?label.` triple pattern and replace `"[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"` with `"en"`. BTW, moving `?Stadt rdfs:label ?label.` inside `SERVICE wikibase:label {...}` should also work.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have done, what you suggested. Actually I get unique names in english, but now all cities comes. I would like to have only the capitals. I do not understand why "?Stadt wdt:P31 wd:Q5119." is not recognized. Can you help me again ?

Comment: They are capitals of provinces etc. Try https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#List_of_present-day_countries_and_capital(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Stanislav Kralin's commnet and the examples [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#List_of_present-day_countries_and_capital(s)), this query returns countries and their capitals:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?capital ?capitalLabel ?coords WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.
  ?country wdt:P36 ?capital.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240} # not a former country
  OPTIONAL { ?capital wdt:P625 ?coords. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
LIMIT 1000
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcapital%20%3FcapitalLabel%20%3Fcoords%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%23%20not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcapital%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoords.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%0ALIMIT%201000)

However [some countries](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20as%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%23%20not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%0AHAVING%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20%3E%201%29%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%0A%0ALIMIT%201000) such as [Bolivia](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q750), [Costa Rica](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q800) and [South Africa](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q258) have more than one capital for some reasons!

To limit each country to one (random) capital, try:

```
SELECT  ?country ?countryLabel ?aCapital ?aCapitalLabel ?coords
WHERE
  { { { SELECT  ?country (SAMPLE(?capital) AS ?aCapital)
        WHERE
          { ?country  wdt:P31  wd:Q3624078
            FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?country  wdt:P31  wd:Q3024240 }
            ?country  wdt:P36  ?capital
          }
        GROUP BY ?country
      }
      OPTIONAL
        { ?aCapital  wdt:P625  ?coords }
      SERVICE wikibase:label
        { bd:serviceParam
                    wikibase:language  "en"
        }
    }
  }
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
LIMIT   1000
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FaCapital%20%3FaCapitalLabel%20%3Fcoords%0AWHERE%0A%20%20%7B%20%7B%20%7B%20SELECT%20%20%3Fcountry%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fcapital%29%20AS%20%3FaCapital%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20%20wdt%3AP31%20%20wd%3AQ3624078%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20%20wdt%3AP31%20%20wd%3AQ3024240%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20%20wdt%3AP36%20%20%3Fcapital%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3FaCapital%20%20wdt%3AP625%20%20%3Fcoords%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%20%22en%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%0ALIMIT%20%20%201000)